# tomcat timing out a process at 120 minutes

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a long-run job on Tomcat. It's a data conversion to update the database for a new release, in case you wonder. On our development server it took 7 hours to run but completed with no problems. Every 60 seconds it sends a progress message to the browser to let you know it's still alive and keep the connection active.

Then I tried to run it on a different server and after 120 minutes it failed with an exception, "getAttribute: Session already invalidated". I restarted it and again it failed with the same message after 120 minutes. It had a feature to restart at certain key points so I started it at "part 2" and again it died at 120 minutes.

I conclude something in the server is imposing a time limit of 120 minutes -- it's too much of a coincidence for it to die due to a program bug at exactly the same elapsed time 3 times in a row, especially when the third run would have been different data.

The Tomcat <session-timeout> on our development server was set to 30, and on that server it ran 7 hours no problem, so whatever limit that's imposing, I don't think that's it.

Any clues as to what's shooting me down? I'm guessing there's another sort of timeout in there somewhere, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Is it possible that simply the session timeout in Tomcat is 120 minutes and you haven't used it for that long? Based on the error message may I suggest some diagnostic steps? Add `HttpSessionListener` and print stack trace on `sessionDestroyed` (trapping it with a breakpoint would be even better). You will then be able to determine which mechanism in Tomcat invalidates the session in the middle of the process (invalidation thread, your own code...)

Comment: I could try that and see if it gives any useful into. I can't set a breakpoint, because it doesn't fail when I run from any server where we actually have a development environment. It only fails when I run on the testing department's server. I suppose it would be an interesting experiment to see if they'll give me access to deploy a development environment on that server and run.

Answer (score 3):

Could you just background the job and have it update a resource that would allow you to poll for the status instead of maintaining the connection the entire time?

You could easily do this with a Thread.

Comment: Yes, I certainly could. Actually, as this is a one-time data conversion, it doesn't need to be pretty, I'm thinking of just pulling the whole thing out of the web app and turning it into a command-line program. But I'm baffled about what the problem is. Sometimes you just have to accept a workaround, but I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose stuff like this because the problem could be at so many different levels. Tomcat, Server, Firewall, Router, Browser, Workstation. It could be timing out anywhere along the way.

Comment: Well, the fact that the message says that the SESSION no longer exists would seem to me to indicate that the problem is within Tomcat and not, say, a firewall issue. Of course, error messages can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

From [here:](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)

org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK

If this is true or if org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE is true Tomcat will track the number of active requests for each session. When determining if a session is valid, any session with at least one active request will always be considered valid.

If not specified, the default value of false will be used.